# Does the Candle item work with It Is Meant To Be?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

Can you use the "Candle item card" with the "It Is Meant To Be" event card, in order to roll 5 dice instead of 4 to use later as the card describes?

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot.

Candle says:

> If you draw an event card, roll 1 additional die (maximum of 8 dice) for that event's **trait rolls**.

(Emphasis mine)

It Is Meant To Be says:

> You can choose instead to roll 4 dice and write down the result. [...]

The dice rolling for It Is Meant To Be is not a "trait roll".

A trait roll is one where you are rolling a number of dice equal to one of your traits (Speed, Might, Sanity, or Knowledge). "Roll 4 dice" is not making a trait roll.

From the rules:

> Sometimes a card or room
>   tile tells you to attempt
>   a roll based on one of
>   your explorer’s traits
>   (Speed, Might, Sanity, or
>   Knowledge). When that
>   happens, roll as many dice
>   as your explorer currently
>   has in that trait. For
>   example, if your explorer
>   must attempt a Sanity roll,
>   and she currently has a
>   Sanity of 4, roll 4 dice and
>   add the dots together to
>   get the result. Whether you
>   succeed or fail, the card or
>   tile will tell you the results
>   of your attempt.

This rule does not specifically define "trait roll", but it strongly implies that "trait roll" is either "sanity roll", "might roll", "speed roll", or "knowledge roll"; because it defines a "trait" as one of those 4 things.